# Nginx, show the folder tree, virtualhost

Tags: nginx, tree, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I want to show the folder tree from folder in datas which contains logs from CMS I have installed.
Here my datas file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server{
        listen 80;
#       listen *:80;
        server_name datas.test.nx;
        location / {
                root /opt/datas/logs;
        }
}
```

But when I go in datas.test.nx I have an error 403 Forbidden. I have tried to show an index.html I put in /home/user/index.html and it works, but when I want to show the folder tree of datas/logs I have this error.
I put chmod 777 on all my folder /datas/* and a chown www-data:www-data /datas/* too.
Have you any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: As in a directory listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable directory listing. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name datas.test.nx;
    root /opt/datas/logs;
    location / {
         autoindex on;
    }
}
```